# Opening a specific PDF sharepoint-document in Chrome

Tags: pdf, chrome

Edge is not good in handling PDF's. I have a PDF where I link in that document between the different pages (from 1 to 3 to 2 to 1 to 4, etc.). Edge can not do this, Chrome can.

I want this one specific document to open with Chrome, NOT default opening all PDF's in Chrome. Is there any way to achieve this? I prefere to open that link from either sharepoint or a sharepoint-page (within a textblok?) but opening it from wihtin an Office-document (perferably Word) is also fine with me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sasa, this isn't SharePoint question. This is more of a HTML question. "Edge is not good in handling PDF's." isn't true. It just handles them differently. The new chromium Edge works just like Chrome.

If you are trying to control an application launch via a link you use a specific URL schema in the href. But again, this is dependent on the user's system, and it isn't guaranteed to work. i.e. you may have to create a link for iOS devices that is different for andriod devices that is different for Windows Devices. etc

Here is information on using the  tag and you need to specific a customer URL Scheme in the href property.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-a-href-attribute-explained/

Here is one example on how to do this for iOS devices:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142834/creating-a-url-that-always-opens-in-chrome